# Find XAML file for current screen

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to `WPF`, I have one screen before me. I reached there after so many navigation hence it is difficult for me to find which XAML file is associated with current screen. In `Asp.Net`, if no routing is used, we can find `aspx` file by URL. Is there any way to quickly find out XAML file?

Comment: Downvoters can explain the reason

Comment: On a side note: if it is difficult to recognize the screen you might have too many screens or have given the screens names/layouts that are not recognizable enough (if you don't know where you are how should a user know?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you attempted doing a search on the window title?

I would suggest identifying static text on your XAML page and then doing a "Find All" for that text.

For example, perhaps you could search on the title of the XAML page.
You could also search for labels as well.

Answer (score -3):

No you cannot find out the name of current xaml file. You have to go through the flow of your application.